# Tab control clears the Selectedindex of Datagridview Combobox column

Tags: c#, gridview

Tab control clears the Selectedindex of Datagridview Combobox column, and every time I change the Combobox, it returning to the last selected value before hitting tab.

Can you please help me to figure out the problem?

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Add some tags to your question and show us some code. The decribed behaviour could be some wrong initialization in your code.